# Skip internal raster image processing of PostScript printer

Tags: printing, ghostscript, postscript

Is there anyway to skip the internal ripping process of a postscript laser printer by using something like ghostscript to produce a directly printable rasterized image? From what I understand, a postscript laser printer receives a postscript print job from the printer driver and internally processes this to produce a printable rasterized image. My goal is to do this locally on a pc with more processing power to quickly keep large variable print jobs in ready-to-print form coming to the printer. Can anyone please help me crack this case? I have searched everywhere for information on this, but it's very difficult to come by. :(

By the way I have a Lexmark C782 with modified firmware and absolutely no documentation from Lexmark about the modifications. (Though this shouldn't be a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

If your printer supports some mode input mode other than PostScript, then yes, but it depends totally on your printer. It also means that you will be bypassing any optimisations the printer manufatcturer has built into their rip, sucah as enhancved screening, to produce higher quality output.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply KenS, could you tell me a little more about this "input mode" you mentioned? I know that this printer understands PCL and PostScript. Maybe you can give me some keywords to work with? Any hint would help. :)

Comment: Both PCL and PostScript may contain raster data, but what you seem to want would be some kind of 'raw' input, whereby you render to a bitmap on a host machine, and then send that to the printer, presumably for perfomance. Very few printers have a 'raw' input. You could render to a bitmap, wrap that up as PostScript (or PCL) and send it to the printer, but its not obvious that would gain you anything over sending the original PostScript.

Comment: On-demand printing certainly used to work by pre-ripping the input to bitmaps, in order to get up to the the thousand of pages per minute required in that niche. However that required printers designed to work that way. Depending on the nature of your input, its possible you could use the ps2write device to process the input files and produce new PostScript files which may run faster.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried printing over port 9100 which says it accepts raw data. I sent a very large bitmap and it started printing much faster than an equally large postscript print job! So it seems as though this approach is what I'm looking for. My only problem now is it defaults to printing from the paper tray but I need it to print from another paper source (roll of labels through the universal feeder). The universal feeder is set as the "default paper source" but it ignores this setting completely. My question now would be: How can one set the paper source at print time over port 9100? PJL?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea, I suspect this may be something specific to your printer.

Comment: The standard operation of a postscript printer is that raster images sent to the device at raster resolution, that the image data will be loaded directly into the raster buffer. Raster images are rather large and communications often slow, so adding a lossless compression would probably improve speed and performance.

Comment: What do you really want to know? You ask about "a laser printer", but do you really want to know how to drive device resolution raster data into the specific printer you have on hand? Are you looking for the command to tell this printer from which paper tray to pull media? If so, your question is about how to drive this printer, not about using the PostScript interpreter or language.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the replies and sorry for my late one. My boss decided to drop the case since it seemed unsolvable. I decided to return to this topic on my own today because somehow I cannot accept no for an answer. It still bothers me! Here's the problem:

Comment: Our laser printing system takes in a large roll of labels on the left side, feeds the roll through a little box that contains a knife for cutting, then continues through the laser printer itself, prints a series of labels, and rolls the labels back onto a little cylinder on the right side. When its finished printing the knife cuts the label and the process comes to an end.

Comment: This process works very well when the print job isn't variable. In other words when the printed image is always the same. As soon as we try printing variable data, such as dates, barcodes, etc. something happens and the printer decides to cut the roll. We think that the printer works so well with non-variable prints because it loads the print job once, keeps it in memory (or wherever) and continuously prints the same job over and over. With variable data, it has to rasterize the image everytime.

Comment: This seems to go out of sync with the roll feeding mechanism and at some point it decides to cut the roll. Maybe the printer doesn't receive data on time? Maybe it takes too long to rasterize?

Comment: The interesting thing is, when I try to print variable data with a custom program written in java the printer can print the entire roll. The main difference here is that the image that is sent by java is just 72 dpi. This is what brought me to thinking that it could be a problem with the internal rasterization of the printer? I thought if I could get the print job into a ready to print form on the PC and then send this directly to the printer that it would skip the internal processes and just print right away. My idea was to use GhostScript to achieve this? I'm not sure what to do really...

Comment: It certainly sounds like a problem with the printer, and if it were me I'd take it up with the manufacturer. If its supposed to be able to do what you want, and it can't, then its broken...... You can use Ghostscript to render PostScript (or PDF) but you are left with your paper tray problem. As someone pointed out, this isn't a PostScript of Ghostscript problem and we aren't really going to be able to help you with it. Again, I'd refer back to the manufacturer. By the way, is this a 72 DPI printer ? If not then you aren't doing a fair comparison sending a 72 dpi image

Comment: Apparently its 1200x1200 so its hardly surpising that a 72 dpi image should print much faster. I wouldn't count on a 1200 dpi image printing at the speed you seem to need.